# How can I add API Key authentication to oData Connector?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I am brand new to Power BI and am looking to find a way to connect to an oData service that requires an API Key. I was asked to create an oData connector but I am open to other ideas as well.

I've never written a connector. When I try connecting to the endpoint using the built in connector, I cannot connect with a Web API key because an API key name is provided. The things I've found on the web do not make sense to me as a lot of them require the advanced editor. The advanced editor is disabled for me for some reason. Any guidance would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
let
        theData = OData.Feed(
            "<API URL>",
            null,
            [
                Headers = 
                [
                    #"ApiKey" = "<YOUR API KEY>"
                ]
            ]
        ),
        JSONTable = Json.Document(theData),
        message = "Hello World!"
    in
        JSONTable;
```